# On event registration confirmation field labels are being added as classes

Tags: civievent

I have an event registration set up and on the confirmation page the profile's field labels are being applied as classes to the div. For example, I have a profile field with the label 'Will you need lodging all four nights?'. In the source code I get this:

```
<div class="crm-public-form-item crm-section Will you need lodging all four nights?-section">
```

I really don't want the field label to be made classes in the code and the class 'four' is pulling in styles I don't want. Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: i can't help but i may be able to ask clarification that will help others help you. Compare the relevant CMS demo site eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and update your Question with comparison. Confirm your CMS and theme, and civi version.

Comment: I just looked at the demo site and it does the same thing. For the profile field 'Email Address', in the page source I see the div has the class "crm-public-form-item crm-section Email Address-section", this is the same as what I'm seeing so it seems to be universal.